# Python Is there a shutdown equivalent to __init__ ()

Tags: python

I use `__init__()` functions a lot in Python classes to set up things when a class is first called.

Is there an equivalent function that is called when a script is shutting down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the [`__del__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) method which is called when an object is finalized.  However, python doesn't guarantee that `__del__` will actually be called on objects when the interpreter exits.

There are a few alternatives:

- [atexit.register](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html#atexit.register) -- Here you can register a function to run when your script terminates
- create a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) and use the `with` statement.  Then your context manager's `__exit__` method will be called unconditionally when you leave the context.

---

both of these options would fail if you did something really nasty to exit your program (e.g. somehow causing a segmentation fault or exiting via `os._exit`)

Comment: @filmor -- I was just adding that. :)